# formulaCells.forEach is not a function in Office Scripts

Tags: excel, scripting

I am using Office Scripts to get all cells containing formulas and then trying to loop through these formulas. Unfortunately, I run into a mistake.

```
let usedRange = ws.getUsedRange();
let formulaCells = usedRange.getSpecialCells(ExcelScript.SpecialCellType.formulas);
formulaCells.forEach(cell => {
     let oldFor : string = cell.getFormula();
     let newFor = '=IFERROR('+oldFor.replace('=','')+',\"\")';
     cell.setFormula(newFor);
 });
```

The error message is "formulaCells.forEach is not a function".

Any one knows the reason and how to fix this. Thanks in advance.

The error message is "formulaCells.forEach is not a function".